# Compare value of cells of a column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a column as follows:

8856
8867
8876
8856
8898

My objective is to compare each cell of the column and if the values are the same to execute an if statement.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim C1row As Long
Dim C2row As Long
Dim C2TotalRows As Long
Dim CustID As String

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Report")

sht1.Activate
C2TotalRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
C1row = 2

Do While sht1.Cells(C1row, 3).Value <> ""

    CustID = sht1.Cells(C1row, 3).Value

    For C2row = 2 To C2TotalRows

        If CustID = Cells(C2row, 3).Value Then
            MsgBox CustID
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
    C1row = C1row + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What's a problem exactly, what don't work?

Comment: i have data as follows 8856
8867
8876
8856
8898 and i want to compare the data with each other if they are same then run a if loop

Comment: what are you planning to do with the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Just assumption, I see that `C2TotalRows=C2TotalRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))`, which is equal to 1, because of range "A:A". So, `For C2row = 2 To C2TotalRows` this loop will never run. Try specify another cells range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified your code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet
  Dim C1row As Long
  Dim CustID As String
  Dim R As Range

  Set sht1 = Worksheets("Report")
  sht1.Activate
  C1row = 2

  Do While sht1.Cells(C1row, 3).Value <> ""
    CustID = sht1.Cells(C1row, 3).Value
    Set R = sht1.Range("C:C").Find(CustID, sht1.Cells(C1row, 3))
    If R.Row > C1row Then
      MsgBox CustID
    End If
    C1row = C1row + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Good luck and thank you.

Reference: [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)